# One Vector3 related to a plane, copy it to another plane

Tags: c#, math, 3d, xna, unity-game-engine

I really want to copy a Vector3 related to a plane to another plane. You can see the image.
I just want to copy the blue vector3 to be the red vector3.
I trying to find out how to copy it with help of the forward/up/right-vectors for the both planes.

My C#-function I want to create is like this:

```
    public Vector3 CopyVector3RelatedFromOnePlaneToAnother(Vector3 point,
 Vector3 plane1_position, Vector3 plane1_forward, Vector3 plane1_up, Vector3 plane1_right,
 Vector3 plane1_position, Vector3 plane2_forward, Vector3 plane2_up, Vector3 plane2_right)
    {
       // ...
    }
```

[image]

Edited:
Adding the working progress code in C#-unity:

```
Vector3 CopyVector3RelatedFromOnePlaneToAnother(Vector3 point, Transform plane1, Transform plane2)
    {
        // Plane1.
        Matrix4x4 ModelWorldToPlane1 = Matrix4x4.TRS(plane1.position, plane1.rotation, plane1.localScale);
        ModelWorldToPlane1 = ModelWorldToPlane1.transpose;

        // Plane2.
        Matrix4x4 ModelWorldToPlane2 = Matrix4x4.TRS(plane2.position, plane2.rotation, plane2.localScale);
        ModelWorldToPlane2 = ModelWorldToPlane2.transpose;

        Vector3 pInCoord1 = ModelWorldToPlane1.inverse * point;
        Vector3 pTransformedInCoord1 = ModelWorldToPlane1.inverse * ModelWorldToPlane2 * pInCoord1;
        Vector3 pTransformedInWorld = ModelWorldToPlane1 * pTransformedInCoord1;

        return pTransformedInWorld;
    }
```

Is there someone who can help me with that? Regards!

Comment: You can use a proper transformation matrix. However, this problem is not uniquely solvable using two `Plane` objects. The plane just contains the up vector, thus you are missing the plane's orientation (forward and right). How do you want to go about this?

Comment: Oh, right. Now I just changed planes to just vector3 for position, forward, right up. :)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, we construct the model transformations from world space to the planes' spaces:

```
                        / right1.x   up1.x   forward1.x   position1.x \
                        | right1.y   up1.y   forward1.y   position1.y |
ModelWorldToPlane1  =   | right1.z   up1.z   forward1.z   position1.z |
                        \     0        0         0             1      /
```

Do the same for plane 2.

**Step 1: Express the point in the coordinate system of plane 1**:

```
pInCoord1 = (ModelWorldToPlane1)^-1 * p
```

**Step 2: Transform the point to plane 2 (still expressed in the coordinates of plane 1**:

```
pTransformedInCoord1 = (ModelWorldToPlane1)^-1 * ModelWorldToPlane2 * pInCoord1
```

**Step 3: Express the new point in world space**:

```
pTransformedInWorld = ModelWorldToPlane1 * pTransformedInCoord1
```

So overall:

```
pTransformedInWorld = ModelWorldToPlane1 * (ModelWorldToPlane1)^-1 * ModelWorldToPlane2 * (ModelWorldToPlane1)^-1 * p
                    = ModelWorldToPlane2 * (ModelWorldToPlane1)^-1 * p
```

This is the mathematical representation. You have to map this to an XNA equivalent. Be aware that XNA uses row vector layout. This basically means that matrices are transposed. Therefore, the multiplication order is reversed.

Comment: Hmm, I really cant get it to work.
It seems that the point don't is related to the plane when I move the point/plane. When I rotate some of the planes, then the copied point rotates the world origin.

Comment: I just calculated an example - the mathematical concept is correct. Unity seems to use column vector layout for matrices. So you don't need to transpose the matrices. To transform a vector you can use `MultiplyPoint3x4()` which is supposed to be a bit faster. Have you checked the temporary results? Do they seem reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the red point to be in the same location relative to plane2 that the blue point is relative to plane1, then the blue and red points have the same position in plane1 space as they do in plane2 space. So if you transform the world space blue point by the inverse of a world space matrix representing plane1, then that is already in plane2 space as well. Then transform that result by the world space matrix representing plane2, you will have the world space position of the red point.

```
//in Xna
Vector3 CopyVector3RelatedFromOnePlaneToAnother(Matrix plane1, Matrix plane2, Vector3 bluePointWorldSpace)
{
   Vector3 planeSpacePosition = Vector3.Transform(bluePointWorldSpace, Matrix.Invert(plane1));
   return Vector3.Transform(planeSpacePosition, plane2);
}
```